# SWIFTUI/FIREBASE: Firebase data is not being fetched/mapped correctly

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui, swiftui-list

https://www.loom.com/share/72e124ba35fe44489e472c1d442c751a

^^HERE IS A QUICK VIDEO WHERE I DEMO THE BUG AND THE CODE!!! ANY HELP WOULD BE EXTREMELY APPRECIATED! THANK YOU!

ISSUE: Cant fetch the list of users in realtime seamlessly.. either doesn't fetch right away or produces duplicate results.

import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import SDWebImageSwiftUI
import SwiftUI

//THE VIEWMODEL

```
@MainActor
class ContactsViewModel: ObservableObject {

  @Published var user: User
  @Published var userRequestInboxUsers = [User]()
  @Published var emergencyContactUsers = [User]()

  init(user: User) {
    self.user = user
    self.fetchTheUsersRequests()
    // self.fetchTheUsersContacts()
    self.fetchContacts()
  }

  //this function works correctly
  func fetchTheUsersRequests() {

    guard let uid = user.id else { return }
    let query = COLLECTION_FOLLOWERS.document(uid).collection("inbox").whereField(
      "currentStatus", isEqualTo: "isPending")

    query.addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: true) { snapshot, error in
      if let error = error {
        print("There was an error querying the inbox requests: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      } else {

        for request in snapshot!.documents {

          COLLECTION_USERS.document(request.documentID).getDocument { snapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
              print("There was an error fetching the user data: \(error)")
            } else {
              guard let userRequestInInbox = try? snapshot?.data(as: User.self) else { return }
              self.userRequestInboxUsers.append(userRequestInInbox)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //this is the first function I wrote to try and fetch the contacts
  //this func works in mapping the user however it initially shows duplicate data.... I think this is because im appending instead of assigning
  func fetchTheUsersContacts() {
    guard let uid = user.id else { return }

    let query = COLLECTION_FOLLOWERS.document(uid).collection("inbox").whereField(
      "currentStatus", isEqualTo: "emergencyContact")

    query.addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: true) { snapshot, error in
      if let error = error {
        print("There was an error querying the emergency contacts: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      } else {
        for userContact in snapshot!.documents {
          COLLECTION_USERS.document(userContact.documentID).getDocument { snapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
              print("There was an error fetching the user data: \(error)")
            } else {
              guard let contact = try? snapshot?.data(as: User.self) else { return }
              self.emergencyContactUsers.append(contact)
            }
          }
        }

      }
    }
  }

  //this is the Second function I wrote to try and fetch the contacts
  //this function doesnt duplicate the data however it doesnt properly map to my user object. It only gives me access to the users's ID
  func fetchContacts() {

    guard let uid = user.id else { return }

    let query = COLLECTION_FOLLOWERS.document(uid).collection("inbox").whereField(
      "currentStatus", isEqualTo: "emergencyContact")

    query.addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: true) { snapshot, error in

      guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {
        print("no contacts yet...")
        return
      }
      self.emergencyContactUsers = documents.compactMap { (mapUser) -> User? in
        print(mapUser.documentID)
        return try? mapUser.data(as: User.self)
      }

    }
  }

}
```

//THE USER OBJECT

```
struct User: Codable, Identifiable, Equatable {

  //firebase uid becomes the handle
  @DocumentID var id: String?

  //The username cant have duplicates in the database + is how users search other users to add them to their special friends list
  var fullName: String?
  var userName: String?
  var age: Double?
  var sex: String?
  var weight: Double?
  var height: String?
  var eyeColor: String?
  var hairColor: String?
  var homeAddress: String?
  var identifyingFeatures: String?
  var shoeSize: Double?
  var phone: String?
  var profileImageUrl: String?

  //where the current location of the user is stored and the property called whenever a user needs to share their loco
  //var location: CLLocation?
}
```

//THE VIEW

```
struct ContactsView: View {

  var user: User
  @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContactsViewModel

  init(user: User) {
    self.user = user
    self.viewModel = ContactsViewModel(user: user)
  }

  var body: some View {

    NavigationView {
      ScrollView {

        Rectangle()
          .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 1 / 10)
          .foregroundColor(.white)

        VStack(spacing: 20) {
          NavigationLink {
            SearchView()
          } label: {
            SearchButton()
          }

          Divider()

          NavigationLink {
            UserRequestList(user: user)
          } label: {
            ZStack {
              RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 70)

              Text("Your current requests").foregroundColor(.white)
            }
          }
        }

        Divider()

        Text("Your Emergency Contacts:").bold()
          .foregroundColor(.green)
          .padding(.vertical)

        ForEach(viewModel.emergencyContactUsers) { user in
          NavigationLink {
            EmergencyContactsDetailView(user: user)
          } label: {
            UserRequestCell(user: user)
              .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
              .foregroundColor(.green)
          }
        }

        Divider()

        Rectangle()
          .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 1 / 10)
          .foregroundColor(.white)

      }
    }
    .onAppear {
      print(viewModel.emergencyContactUsers.description)
    }
    .navigationBarTitle("")
    .navigationBarHidden(true)
    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
  }

}
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful to boil your problem down to the actual piece that's causing the problem. You could write a simple test case to showcase that individual problem. In your whole video and your post you never actually ask a question. I appreciate all the effort but it's going to be harder to get an answer with the deluge of information without a specific question. It also seems like you have multiple problems, I'd focus on one per post.

Comment: You might try doing `print(mapUser)` to see the whole user object instead of just the id. It seems to me that the table you are querying doesn't have all the user data, you might have to fetch it separately.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.